# Docusign Event Notification recipient events update not triggering

Tags: events, notifications, docusignapi

```
"<eventNotification>" +
                    "<url>" +
                        Tyc.Website.Properties.Settings.Default.DocusignStatusAPIUrl +
                    "</url>" +
                    "<loggingEnabled>" +
                        true +
                    "</loggingEnabled>" +
                    "<requireAcknowledgment>" +
                        true +
                    "</requireAcknowledgment>" +
                    "<includeDocuments>" +
                        true +
                    "</includeDocuments>" +
                    "<EnvelopeEvents>" +
                        "<envelopeEvent>" +
                            "<envelopeEventStatusCode>" + "Completed" + "</envelopeEventStatusCode>" +
                            "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                        "</envelopeEvent>" +
                        "<envelopeEvent>" +
                             "<envelopeEventStatusCode>" + "Sent" + "</envelopeEventStatusCode>" +
                             "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                        "</envelopeEvent>" +
                        "<envelopeEvent>" +
                             "<envelopeEventStatusCode>" + "Delivered" + "</envelopeEventStatusCode>" +
                             "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                        "</envelopeEvent>" +
                        "<envelopeEvent>" +
                             "<envelopeEventStatusCode>" + "Sent" + "</envelopeEventStatusCode>" +
                             "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                        "</envelopeEvent>" +
                        "<envelopeEvent>" +
                             "<envelopeEventStatusCode>" + "Sent" + "</envelopeEventStatusCode>" +
                             "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                        "</envelopeEvent>" +
                    "</EnvelopeEvents>" +
                    "<RecipientEvents>" +
                        "<recipientEvent>" +
                            "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                            "<recipientEventStatusCode>" + "Sent" + "</recipientEventStatusCode>" +
                        "</recipientEvent>" +
                        "<recipientEvent>" +
                            "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                            "<recipientEventStatusCode>" + "Delivered" + "</recipientEventStatusCode>" +
                        "</recipientEvent>" +
                        "<recipientEvent>" +
                            "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                            "<recipientEventStatusCode>" + "Completed" + "</recipientEventStatusCode>" +
                        "</recipientEvent>" +
                        "<recipientEvent>" +
                            "<includeDocuments>" + true + "</includeDocuments>" +
                            "<recipientEventStatusCode>" + "AutoResponded" + "</recipientEventStatusCode>" +
                        "</recipientEvent>" +
                    "</RecipientEvents>" +
                "</eventNotification>"
```

I use the above request body for docusign event notification. I also tried  instead of  and am able to get status updates for envelope events but i am not receiving status updates for recipient events. What am i missing here?

Comment: Are events happening simultaneously? 

"Note: In cases where multiple events for a single envelope or recipient are queued, only
one set of XML data with the most recent change is published to a customer’s listener.
Example: For an envelope with one signer, when the signer finishes signing the envelope
an Envelope Signed event is triggered, then the DocuSign system processes the envelope,
and then an Envelope Completed event is triggered. If both of these events are in the
Connect queue at the same time, only the Envelope Completed event is sent to a
customer’s listener."

Comment: The above is from page 8 of the [DocuSign Connect Guide](https://www.docusign.com.au/sites/default/files/connect-guide_0.pdf)